# Protect against form / hidden inputs being altered via Inspector (specifically w/ WordPress)

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

I feel like WordPress may have built in helper functions to aid with this?

In a simple plugin I'm developing, I have a form where a user can essentially rate a post. So there are some fields, for example, for `rating`, `user_id`, `post_id`.

In the JavaScript, I'm successfully validating the rating:

```
if ( !data.rating || isNaN(data.rating) || data.rating< 1 || data.rating> 5 )
    // error
```

However, I do not know how to validate the `user_id` or `post_id`?
If a user changes the hidden input user_id value from their ID to say, 1, well - that's not an invalid input. The value "1" is a number, and there is a user with ID 1 so there's no way to determine it's been tampered with? Same with post_id.

Comment: You can't prevent people from changing code via Inspector so I wouldn't bother with that. People will always try to game the system whenever they can, and in this case they can. Instead, make sure to server side validate/sanitize the data received via the form so 1) the user ID actually exists and matches the user that's currently logged in (personally I would not pass the user ID with the form), 2) the post ID exists and the user hasn't voted it yet, 3) the rating value is an integer and not something else, and 4) that the submitted rating value falls between the expected range (1 to 5).

Comment: @cabrerahector Good start but I kinda don't want the user to be able to specify "any" post to rate, even if it would in the end be valid - this got me thinking and so far it seems to work, i just hash together the user_id and post_id and store that in a third hidden field. Then, check the hash in the backend. Can probably be reverse-engineered but it's not so serious and I doubt anyone will care enough-

Comment: People will care enough if they can get something from it.

Answer (score -1):

You could try marking the user_id, and post_id fields as read only.  That way you can set their values on the page and they won't change

[See this link for an example](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_readonly.asp)